# How can I automatically move people?

Tags: animation

I'm making my first animation with people. I downloaded 6 characters from Mixiamo, with a simple walk animation in position. For my animation, it's an archvisualization of an urban place - I need a lot of people. I'm proceeding like this:

1. Rig the characters.
2. Make a follow path by the rig, to a bezier curve.
3. Repeat manually copying the 6 characters I've for source.

It's a very expensive process for the time. I've tried to array the characters but I can't because I would have to make an array to each part of my characters.

So my question is, how can I automate the process or just make the follow path like a particle system?

[image]

Comment: what happens if you simply link-duplicate (alt D) character+armature+path?

Comment: I 've tried, it duplicate all, including the follow path, so i guess, i have to do at all my characters and then duplicate the bezier curve, and game' s done. Thank you so much man!!!!

Comment: Ray i' ve notice a problem, doing like this is coping also the exactly movement of the follow path and the same person is near to my copy and i' ve to remake the follow path every time

Comment: it should not happen, also you could simply link-duplicate the character and move them wherever you want in the scene, they will follow the same path except they will be offset

Comment: Ok i solve that problem thank you. Have you some tips for lag? Cause is lagging a lot

Comment: So what did you finally choose to do? If it lags it's probably because your meshes are high-poly? so you should rather use low-poly with Subdivision Surface modifier